# Interactive Creation

Tags: modeling

Interactive Creation

You can position and scale primitives as you create them using your mouse, without having to use transformation tools.
This options in Maya. 
Is it possible to make such an option for a blender?

Comment: Just press `F6` and adjust the settings after adding the new primitive to the scene. The answer to your question is *yes*, but consider that each primitive has different properties... a use case would help solving your issue. Also you should think about: How many times you need that on a daily basis? IMHO replicating such simple functionalities isn't worth it, when there is a good way in blender already - both packages are totally different.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbK9al4pMbE
see this video for addons q_p this add interactive method in blender.